# WiFi-connected device to control (via infrared) air conditioner and light, with maintained open source apps and SDK

Tags: home-electronics, smart-home

I want to start my air conditioner at 7am in the morning, and via my phone when coming back from work.

So, I am looking for a device with the characteristics below:

## Hardware

- Can connect to my home WiFi to receive instructions from the web.
- Can switch on/off my air conditioner. And also my cell lighting if possible.
- Can switch them on/off from a distance of 10 meters.
- As small as possible.
- As power-efficient as possible.
- Using wall outlet electricity, not batteries.
- Ideally contains a room temperature sensor.

## API

- The API should require authentication.
- The API should be open and documented.

## Software

- Open source apps should be available for Android, if possible for iOS too.
- Maintained by a sizable community (commits by different people in the last few months).
- Ideally the sources/schematics for the hardware should be open source too.

## Appliances to control

- Air conditioner: Fujitsu AS-J25C-W
- Light (if possible): Panasonic HH-CC0834A